# NSNumber/NSDecimalNumber bizarre behavior

Tags: swift, macos

Following code produces bizarre result for a test case I just happened to choose. Code from playground, followed by result

```
import Cocoa

func spellDollars(_ amount: Decimal) -> String {
    let fDollars = NumberFormatter()
    fDollars.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.spellOut
    let fCents = NumberFormatter()
    fCents.format = "00"
    let c = (amount * 100 as NSDecimalNumber).intValue % 100
    let cents = fCents.string(from: NSNumber(value: c))!
    let d  = (amount as NSDecimalNumber).intValue
    print(d, c, amount)
    let dollars = fDollars.string(from: NSNumber(value: d))!.capitalized
    let s = "\(dollars) and \(cents)/100"
    return s
}

print(spellDollars(1019123.08))
```

Result:

-825551 -32 1019123.0799999997952
Minus Eight Hundred Twenty-Five Thousand Five Hundred Fifty-One and -32/100

Comment: What do you think the correct output should be?

Comment: 1019123 08 (Don't care about the rounding error.) and the same result spelled out. Works fine for one penny more, one penny less.

Comment: Just for clarification, here's what it gets for one penny less:

Comment: 1019123 7 1019123.07
One Million Nineteen Thousand One Hundred Twenty-Three and 07/100

Answer (score 3):

Bottom line, the problem is that you called `spellDollars` with a `Double`, which it converted to a `Decimal`. You could do:

```
print(spellDollars(Decimal(string: "1019123.08")!))
```

Or

```
print(spellDollars(Decimal(sign: .plus, exponent: -2, significand: 101912308)))
```

And both of those would have worked without introducing this `Double` to `Decimal` conversion noise.

---

Consider a simplified example:

```
let decimal1 = Decimal(floatLiteral: 1019123.08)
let decimal2 = Decimal(string: "1019123.08")!
let decimal3 = Decimal(sign: .plus, exponent: -2, significand: 101912308)

for value in [decimal1, decimal2, decimal3] {
    print(value)
}
```

That will output:

> 1019123.0799999997952 
>   1019123.08 
>   1019123.08

To understand why that `Double` in the first example gets converted to a `Decimal` value of `1019123.0799999997952`, I’d suggest you refer to [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

---

Regarding why you’re getting -825551 from `intValue`, I’d guess it’s some overflow resulting from a significand (10191230799999997952) that is so large that it can’t be represented in an integer format or something like that.

I’d suggest cutting the Gordian knot and not use `NSDecimalNumber` arithmetic to manually round values. Use the [`NSDecimalRound`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1412204-nsdecimalround) function, e.g.

```
func spellDollars(_ amount: Decimal) -> String {
    // instantiate formatters

    let dollarsFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    dollarsFormatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
    let centsFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    centsFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 2

    // get dollars

    var inputAmount = amount
    var dollars = Decimal.zero
    NSDecimalRound(&dollars, &inputAmount, 0, .down)

    // get dollars and cents

    var dollarsAndCents = Decimal.zero
    NSDecimalRound(&dollarsAndCents, &inputAmount, 2, .plain)

    // get cents

    let cents = (dollarsAndCents - dollars) * 100

    // build strings

    let centsString = centsFormatter.string(for: cents)!
    let dollarsString = dollarsFormatter.string(for: dollars)!.capitalized
    return "\(dollarsString) and \(centsString)/100"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. (My 2nd example had different input, one penny less, to show that spellDollars worked, sometimes.) Still seems like bizarre behavior that some doubles work, some give off-the-chart results. Expected to deal with rounding issues, pure luck to stumble on this test case. Thanks again.

Comment: Many fractional `Double` values cannot be accurately represented in decimal (as described in that article I linked to above). This is a very common problem. Bottom line, always avoid supplying fractional `Double` or `Float` to `Decimal` initializer or method argument unless you are doing explicit rounding after the conversion has taken place.

Comment: Wasn't the rounding that threw me, was getting -825551 for the whole number part.

Comment: @Ron - I agree that that’s pretty weird. I suspect some weird significand overflow. I’d suggest you retire `NSDecimalNumber` casting and just use `NSDecimalRound`, designed explicitly for rounding `Decimal` numbers.

Comment: Thanks. It's an accounting (ugh!) application. I factored all the arithmetic into a structure anyway, so I think I'll just deal with integers and insert the decimal in the right place for display. Sales tax & discounts I just have to be careful. 64 bits is plenty!

Comment: FWIW, I’m not sure I’d give up on `Decimal` so fast and use integers instead. `Decimal` is explicitly intended for any apps where accurate decimal representations are needed. That’s `Decimal`’s entire _raison d'etre._ It only has challenges if one starts getting fast and loose, casually casting `Float` and `Double` numbers to `Decimal`. But, certainly, do whatever you are more comfortable with.