# Create NSDecimalNumber or Decimal from a Double in Swift

Tags: swift, decimal

Trying to create a ***Decimal*** (or NSDecimalNumber) out of the given ***Double*** value for MONEY calculations within my app. I am using Swift 4 in Xcode 10.

But it generates following values which are wrong.

```
let doubleVal: Double = 56.203
Decimal(doubleVal)               // Wrong Answer: 56.20299999999998976
Decimal.init(doubleVal)          // Again Wrong Answer: 56.20299999999998976
```

If I use the ***String initialization***, that works ***correct***.

```
Decimal(string: "56.203")!      // Correct Decimal: 56.203
```

I remember had the same problem in java when work with BigDecimal if call constructor with a double value. E.g. new BigDecimal(double val)... So they have this extra method **valueOf** `BigDecimal.valueOf(amount);` that creates correct BigDecimal out of the double.

How do I generate a Decimal out of a given Double value with Swift?

Comment: Your `let doubleVal: Double = 56.203` is already “imprecise” because a binary floating point number cannot store that exact value. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/42781785/1187415 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/54621386/1187415. Creating the decimal number from a string is a correct solution.

Comment: This is NOT regarding Rounding. I had the same problem in Android with Java and they have this extra method as a fix to the problem. BigDecimal.valueOf(amount). MONEY calculations should use Decimal to avoid these cases

Comment: This is NOT regarding Rounding or create Decimal with String value as I have mention in my question. Dont know how this become a duplcate for this two links.

Comment: @JibW floating point literals are always stored as `Double`. So if you declare a value as a floating point literal, there's no way to not lose precision and be able to later convert it into `Decimal` while keeping the correct value. This is a duplicate, since the duplicate targets do explain why the issue exists and how to overcome it.

Comment: Your `doubleVal` does not contain the exact value 56.203, but some approximation of it. So the precision is lost *before* your create the Decimal. Creating a Decimal from a string is a possible solution (as you already figured out). More possible approaches are shown in https://stackoverflow.com/q/42781785/1187415.

Comment: Note that Java's [BigDecimal.valueOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf(double))  converts the double to a string first and then creates the BigDecimal from that string ...

Comment: The other way, besides using `Decimal(string: "56.203")`, is to specify the exponent and integer significand, e.g. `let value = Decimal(sign: .plus, exponent: -3, significand: 56203)`

Answer (score 1):

When Swift is converting a base 10 decimal number (`56.203`) to a binary number, there will always be some [floating point error](https://youtu.be/PZRI1IfStY0). As you have stated that you are using these for money calculation, `Int` is recommended (maybe multiply by 1000 when showing to users?).

Comment: That's why this Decial class is there to avoid these floating poit errors. String initialisation works ok it's this double initialiazation have the issue. Surely there should be a proper way to overcome this like JAVA HAS.

Comment: If multiply by thousand it is 56202 which is wrong. Right one should be 56203 , when multiply by 1000, yeah?

Comment: @JibW Actually, even in Java you have a double. `BigDecimal` then does some mathematical magic to convert the double to a `String` using approximations (therefore it is not the exact decadic value). Then it initializes `BigDecimal` from a `String`. Actually, Swift will have this, but it doesn't yet. Initialize `Decimal` from a `String`.